# xcode não cria storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Alguem sabe porque meu xcode ao criar um single view aplication, ele não cria as storyboard, estou começando agora e na aula a tela do app iphone é feito la, mas no meu aparece apenas um main storyboard, quando eu rodo a aplicação não aparece nada, apenas o nome do projeto.
alguem sabe:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como mencionado pelo [Douglas Ferreira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/1256/douglas-ferreira) o *Xcode 6* inclui as [Size Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html) e com isso basta um storyboard, no entanto isso não te impede de usar diversos storyboards, XIBs ou até mesmo misturá-los!

Para criar um novo arquivo basta fazer <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, selecionar *User Interfaces* em *iOS* e escolher a *User Interface* e não se esqueça de setá-la em *General* nas configurações do projeto.

Se não aparece nada garanta que

- A *User Interface* correta está selecionada
- Os itens incluídos estão em uma região visível
- Você está olhando para o *View Controller* certo no *Interface Builder*

Answer (score 1):

Pelo o que eu entendi parece estar tudo certo. Quando um *Single View Application* é criado seu projeto já vem com uma `Storyboard` e esta é chamada de `Main.storyboard`.

Mas mesmo assim caso queira criar uma nova Storyboard é só ir em `File > New > File... > User Interface > Storyboard`.

Comment: mas antes criava um iphone storyboard, e um ipad storyboard, e agora apenas esse main, sera q é a versão?

Comment: Sim, agora com a nova funcionalidade `Size classes` no Xcode 6, você pode configurar *UI* diferentes para iPhone e iPad sem precisar de outro `storyboard`.

Comment: Mas cara quando eu crio um projeto, e vou na main storyboard, e coloco qualquer componente, e mando executar o projeto, ele apenas abre o emulador com o nome do projeto, nao mostra nada que coloquei la, voce sabe o que é isso?

Answer (score 0):

O arquivo Main.storyboard deve estar localizado no projeto, caso não esteja crie New File >> User Interface >> Storyboard

Quando for usar o storyboard pode fazer da forma abaixo:

`ViewController *viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyboardID"];`

Ao clicar na ViewController dentro do seu arquivo de storyboard defina o ID, como imagem abaixo:
[image: Definir storyboardID]